# SEO friendly URL parameters via .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

**I want to rewrite the URLs from:**

```
https://www.example.com/bibliorafturi/?wpsolr_fq%5B0%5D=pa_culoare_str%3AAlbastru
```

to this:

```
https://www.example.com/bibliorafturi/Albastru
```

**Another example:**

```
https://www.example.com/bibliorafturi/?wpsolr_fq%5B0%5D=pa_culoare_str%3AAlbastru&wpsolr_fq%5B1%5D=pa_brand_str%3AESSELTE
```

to this

```
https://www.example.com/bibliorafturi/Albastru/?wpsolr_fq%5B1%5D=pa_brand_str%3AESSELTE
```

So I need only pa_culoare_str to be SEO friendly.

How can I do this with .htaccess?

**UPDATE:**

This is my .htaccess file now:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/?$
    RewriteRule ^ /%1?wpsolr_fq[%3]=pa_culoare_str:%2 [QSA,L]
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Thank you!

Comment: Just something to keep in mind when searching for answers... It's actually the other way around. You want to re-write the nice, friendly URLs to something your application can easily parse. As in, the friendly URL comes in the request and you rewrite it within your web server to the format expected by your application

Comment: you should've used wp_rewrite plugin for it this is I think wordpress rewrite.